# File Upload to ASP NET MVC Application in IE7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, file-upload, upload, internet-explorer-7

Is there a way how to correctly upload a file to Asp Net Mvc application in Internet Explorer 7?

1. I would like to customize button text, so a pure input type="file" isn't applicable
2. I would like my browse button to have the same style as other buttons, that is be a button, not div, so e.g. valums fileuploader isn't applicable
3. I don't want to get "Access denied" exception (ie7) when submittig a file, so input type="file" somehow should be accessible
4. When uploading a file I don't want the form to be submitted, because other inputs may not be filled by user yet.

Any help would be appreciated. Examples would be awesome!